# Using Keras Model in Flask App with Threading

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, flask, keras

I have 3 working Keras models and each of those I saved it with 2 file **structure.json** (saving Model Structure) and **weight.h5**.

I've built a Flask App to load these model. But currently I can't add threading=True to option of run() like this:

```
api.run(threaded=True)
```

So I am only able to use:

```
api.run()
```

In this flask app I have two different api (1 GET and 1 POST). Because it runs on one thread so it works too slowly. My system has over 100 connections by seconds, and each connection I have to load another Model.

*Note that all of my keras model have the same structure. I only have to load one structure, and whenever a new connection is coming, I load weight to that structure.*

My code in api likes this:

```
# Compile model
json_file = open(formal_model_path, 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')

@api.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
    try:
        model.load_weights(os.path.join(cointainer_folder, 'weight.h5'))
    except Exception:
        return jsonify(
            error_code='model_file_reading_failed'
        )
```

My code ran errors when enabling threading=True at line **model.load_weights[...]**.

Are there any solutions to build multithreading API with loading many different Keras model?

Comment: does your server do any computation? Sorry I am not familiar with Keros

Comment: Because if DOES do heavy computation, then having more than 1 thread will NOT change anything.. because of GIL

Comment: @dgan I don't think problems only in GIL of python. Because if I send 2 POST requests at the same time, it works well. but if POST and GET, it took about 0.5s to be done. So i think I should run at least 2 threads to manage each type of methods

Comment: I am not using Flask with py2.7, but 3.5, and I have an application with multiple users POSTing and GETing at the same time, and hopefully it doesn't take 0.5sec per request. I think it does computations you might not be aware of

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: @Yu-Yang When I run with threading, the variable **model** doesn't exists. It can only predict in the first thread. When other threads are coming, there aren't any **model** to load weight file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are running into two separate problems:

1. You are loading model weights per request. That's a bad idea and will make every request very slow.
2. flask uses multiple threads. Tensorflow models loaded in one thread, must be used in that same thread.

The right place to load models would be an `init` method. You also need to use `tf.get_default_graph()` to make sure that you are loading models and predicting in the same thread.

Here's what your code might look like

```
def init():
    global models
    models = {}
    for idx, model_path in enumerate(model_paths):
        with open(model_path, "r") as fp:
            model = model_from_json(json.load(fp))
            model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
            model.load_weights(os.path.join(model_path, "weights.h5"))
            models[idx] = model

        # save default graph in a global var
        global graph
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

And inside your request handler

```
@api.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    # select your model based on something inside the request
    # making up func !
    model = models[func(request)]

    with graph.as_default():
        model.predict(..)
```